# Is there a way I can exit a parent function whilst inside that parent's child function?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can exit a parent function whilst inside that parent's child function? Sort of like how a child loop can escape it's parent loop with the `break` keyword suffixed with the name of the parent loop like `parent: loop`.

```js
function parent() {

  function child() {
    return child;
  }
  
  child()
  
  console.log("I don't want this code to be run")
  
 }
  
 parent();
  
 console.log("Just printing this means I escaped parent function (from child function)");
```

Comment: `return child()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```js
function parent() {
  quit = false

  function child() {
    quit = true
    return //I want to exit parent function from here
  }

  child()
  if (quit) { 
    return 
  }

  console.log("still inside parent")

}

parent();

console.log("outside parent");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make it with an `if` statement. If the return value of `child` is true, then parent function exits immediately

```js
function parent() {

  function child() {
    return true //I want to exit parent function from here
  }

  if (child()) {
    return;
  }

  console.log("still inside parent")

}

parent();

console.log("outside parent");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can exit a parent function whilst inside that parent's child function?

No, you cannot force the parent function to return from a child function.

With that said, one way to solve this is by returning a value from `child()` that `parent()` can use:

```
function parent() {

  function child() {

    return true;
  }

  if(child())
      console.log("still inside parent")
}
```

This is just like how any two functions interact even if they aren't nested.

Comment: Gutted. I can see why it'd be more complicated than exiting from a nested loop - functions have to return something where loops don't. Still, would be a great functionality if it just made the parent function return `undefined` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using **Callback** function as child?

```
function parent(child) {
   // Do parent stuff
   return child()
   console.log("You'll never reach here.")
}

// Call the parent and do the parent stuff first.
parent(function() {
   // Do child stuff.
   return
})

console.log("You'll be here after running parent followed by child.");
```

Use the **Promise** approach:

```
function parent() {
   return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
         // Do parent stuff.
         resolve(function() {
            // Do child stuff.
            return true
         })
      } 
      catch (error) {
         return reject(error)
      }
   });
   // You'll never reach here.
}

// Call the parent.
parent()
   .then((isChildDone) => {
       if (isChildDone) {
          console.log("You'll be here after running parent followed by child.");
       }
   })
   .catch((error) => {
       // Handle error if child hit error.
   });
```